# How to rename columns in Sparklyr in R?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

This is the code I have used in R via Spark Cluster, and error also given below

```
mydata<-spark_read_csv(spark_cluster,name = "rd_1",path = "IAF_Extracted_Data_Zipped.csv",header = F,delimiter = "|")

mydata %>% select(customer=V1,device_subscriber_id=V2,user_subscriber_id=V3,user_id=V4,location_id=V5)
```

Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'V1' not found

Comment: Could you provide the output of  `str(mydata)`. Also, to be sure to understand it correctly, `customer, device_subscriber_id, etc` are your new names right? Or are those existent objects?

Comment: yes....these are  new names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want specific names just provide a vector of names on read:

```
columns <- c("customer", "device_subscriber_id", 
             "user_subscriber_id", "user_id", "location_id")

spark_read_csv(
   spark_cluster, name = "rd_1",path = "IAF_Extracted_Data_Zipped.csv",
   header = FALSE, columns = columns, delimiter = "|"
)
```

The number of `columns` should match the number of columns in the input.

Answer (score 2):

The renaming convention goes the other way around (`new name` = `old name`)

You are looking for the following:

```
mydata %>% 
    select(V1 = customer,
           V2 = device_subscriber_id,
           V3 = user_subscriber_id,
           V4 = user_id,
           V5 = location_id)
```

Comment: V1....V5 are default column names that I want to change ... Dont you think it should be newname=oldname ?

Comment: i m getting an error like Error: Query contains no columns

Comment: why don't you try `dplyr::select` instead of `select`?

Comment: However, the first thing I would check (the data source) is not available to me. It would be great to have a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head you could try `customer = mydata$V1` and similar for the other variables (assuming `V1,...` are column names of `mydata`).

Comment: This is what I get when I used mydata$column names ......              
 Error: Query contains no columns